# What's a good strategy for generating unique hash keys for a very large collection of images in Python?

Tags: python, hash, unique, key

I have a listing of millions of files and am uploading them to Amazon's S3. I need to create unique keys for each of the images. I'd rather not use md5 because it requires scanning the entire file, which can be slow. Additionally, there could be duplicate images, which is allowed in our application. Any suggestion for quickly generating an almost guaranteed to be unique key? Preferably, 32-characters alpha numeric (can be case sensitive). Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason for wanting to upload duplicate images? If you use the file hash as a key you can store one image and it can be referenced multiple times, compacting the amount of space used.

Comment: Your requirements are deeply flawed. (1) Hashes can only be unique if you know all possible hash inputs beforehand, and even then you have to generate a specialized algorithm. (2) How can you hope for low collisions ignoring most of the input (i.e. not scanning all/most of the file)? (3) Equal inputs should give equal outputs (thus catching duplicate images), otherwise it's not a hash by most definitions.

Comment: Why do you want to hash? Why not just use a unique ID (username+timestamp+number-of-images-user-has-stored)

Answer (score 3):

I would not call this a hash, since that implies generating a unique value based on the file contents.

Instead, [UUIDs](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) might be what you're after.

Comment: Very low if implemented properly, that's the whole point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Just use an MD5 hash on the actual FILE after it's been uploaded and stored.

http://docs.python.org/library/md5.html

Apply hash to database table or, however you're storing it.

Answer (score -1):

MD5 of datetime.now() (at a time of file upload) will be OK, imho.

Comment: you mean Date.now()... and if you're doing that, you don't need the MD5 for uniqueness...